# Proving that operator $x_n \to x_{n+1}/ n$ is compact

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, compact-operators

> Prove that the operator $T:\ell^2\rightarrow\ell^2$ defined as
> \begin{equation}
> Tx = \bigg(x_2, \frac{x_3}{2}, \frac{x_4}{3}, \dots  \bigg)
> \end{equation}for $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots) \in \ell^2$ is compact

I am trying to prove this problem be following approach, first let we defined a sequence of operator $T_n$ such that $T_n x = \bigg(x_2, \frac{x_3}{2}, \frac{x_4}{3}, \dots, \frac{x_{n+1}}{n}, 0, 0, 0, \dots  \bigg)$, which $T_n x$ only doing the operation for first $n$ element for $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots) \in \ell^2$. Each $T_n$ is clearly a compact operator since it is finite rank.

Then if I could show that $T_n x$ converge to $Tx$, then there is a theorem guarantee that the limit of $T_n$, which should be $T$, is also an compact operator. I think this is a right approach, but I am sticking on showing that $\|Tx - T_nx\| \to 0$. I cannot bounded $\|Tx - T_nx\|$ by something like $\|x\|/n$. Could someone can help me on this problem?

Comment: Your approach is fine. Express $\|Tx-T_nx\|^2$ as infinite sum. You will see that it is bounded above by $\|x\|^2/(n+1)^2.$